# TableViewCell Unresolved Identifier when creating cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

in my Xcode Project, I have `the main storyboard` set up with a `table view` and a `prototype cell` with the `identifier` set to "cell". The table view has a `data source outlet` and a `delegate outlet`.
Yet, my build crashes every time because of an "unresolved identifier" when I create the table view in line 11 (see code below).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource 
{

let array = createArray()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return(validDeck.count)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell") |"ERROR: Unknown Identifier 'cell' "
    cell.textlabel?.text = ""
    return cell
}
```

Does anybody know this error and is willing to help?

Comment: Don't use parentheses after `return`, it's not a function e.g. `return validDeck.count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code for swift 3.*

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return validDeck.count // assuming count must be greater then 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

cell.textlabel?.text = "Cell tittle"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: What does the `mTableView` stand for? My ViewController has no attribute mTableView...

Comment: @Narusan Delete `:UITableViewCell` (useless annotation, the compiler can infer the type) and replace  `self.mTableView.` with `tableView.`. Use **always** the table view instance passed as the first parameter.

Comment: @vadian Can you make an edit to clarify what you mean? I don't quite understand. if I delete the self.mTableView, the only thing that is left is the dequeue call...

Comment: @Narusan sorry its `tableView`

Comment: But for some reason, the text label creation doesn't work anymore. `UITableViewCell has no member textlabel`

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `UITableViewCell` instances directly.

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

and then:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for indexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textlabel?.text = ""
    return(cell)
}
```

Comment: I still get an 2 Errors: `Ambiguous reference to member 'tableview_(numberOfRowsInSection)` in viewDidLoad and `cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(wi...` does not work either, Xcode does not accept the for... I'm using Swift3, could this be the reason?

Comment: Not need at all to register cells if they are designed in Interface Builder.